# How to remove a temporary PDF file generated by auto-pst-pdf when I use standalone class?

Tags: pstricks, texstudio, external-files, standalone

Problem of me as the following:

My code is compiled with `pdflatex.exe --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

Its image (use TeXstudio)

[image]

After compiling, there are two files : `filename.pdf` and `filename-pics.pdf`.

## Question

How to ignore one of two files if I use the standalone enviroment? 
May be not?

## Minimal Working Example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{newcent}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-venn}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\psframe(-2.8,-2.8)(2.8,2.8)
\psVenn[bgcircle=false](-1,.5)(0,-1)(1,.5){1.5}{4}
\rput(-1,1.2){A}\rput(1,1.2){B}\rput(0,-2.1){C}
\psline(0,1.3)(.4,2.3)  \uput[20](.3,2.4){$?$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The result :

[image]

P/s: When using the `standalone` environment, they are equivalent.

Comment: the *-pics.pdf is _always_  a helper file and can be deleted if not needed for other cases.

Comment: @Herbert It takes a longer time to compile two files. I don't want so that. :((. But if it is default, I will accept it.

Comment: You do not understand the meaning of the helper file. _You_ have to to do nothing, all is done by package `auto-pst-pdf`. Use `\usepackage[cleanup={log,aux,dvi,ps,pdf}]{auto-pst-pdf}` and _all_ helper files will be deleted in the end. If you are using `standalone` then loading `auto-pst-pdf` makes no sense!

Comment: :((, It seems you have misunderstood. My opinion is if I use standalone then *.pdf and *-pics.pdf are equivalent( alike ). I feel that " *-pics.pdf " superfluous.  And how to ignore " *-pics.pdf " file. As you say, I will accept its survival. P/s: Truly I use PStricks to draw my picture then together with \includegraphics and compile with pdflatex. :-((

Comment: I already wriote that using `standalone` _and_ `auto-pst-pdf` is senseless! The created file `<file>-pics.pdf` is not used by `standalone`. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best practice (recommendation) is as follows.

- Every diagram should be put in separate file using `standalone` document class.
- If you want to use the same font in both diagrams and texts, then create a private package that will be loaded by both the main input file and the diagram input files.
- Always compile the diagram with `latex` followed by `dvips` followed by `ps2pdf` to produce the diagram in PDF. This route is very very fast compared to using `xelatex`. Don't load `auto-pst-pdf` in this diagram input file.
- Load the PDF diagrams from within the main input file using `\includegraphics`, and compile the main input file with `pdflatex`.

## Edit

Responding to your comment about the third step, here is the steps you have to do. I don't use TeXStudio so I am not sure there is a shortcut to invoke all of them in one go. Be careful, the following code turn on `-shell-escape` for the sake of my own purposes.

[image]

## Another Trick

**Second**, write a batch file as follows. Save it with any name as you like, for example, `pstricksbuilder.bat`. Save the file in a safe place so you will not lose it if you format your hard drive in the future.

```
echo off

rem %1 TeX input filename without extension

if exist "%~1.pdf" del "%~1.pdf"

if exist "%~1.tex" latex -shell-escape "%~1.tex"

if exist "%~1.dvi" dvips -t unknown "%~1.dvi"

if exist "%~1.ps" gswin64c -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o "%~1.pdf" "%~1.ps"

for %%x in (aux dvi log out ps toc nav snm) do (if exist "%~1.%%x" del "%~1.%%x")
```

**First**, install GhostScript 64 bit. If you use Ghostscript 32 bit then you have to change the `gswin64c` to `gswin32c` (I think the name is correct).

**Third**, register the batch to the `PATH` environment  variable. I think you know how to do this. If you don't, ask with comments.

[image]

**Fourth**, replace any unused (for example, `DVI Viewer`) TeXStudio command with `pstricksbuilder.bat %`. Done!

**Fifth**, use the following test page.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,3)

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: remove `auto-pst-pdf` package in your input file. Make sure to pass `pstricks` option to `\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}`.

## The simplest trick

Having done the trick given above, you now have another one, the simplest trick. You don't need to register to the PATH, etc but just edit the following.

[image]

Comment: Oh, I fixed it. I misunderstood.

Answer (score 3):

For a `standalone` document the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-venn}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \psframe(-2.8,-2.8)(2.8,2.8)
    \psVenn[bgcircle=false](-1,.5)(0,-1)(1,.5){1.5}{4}
    \rput(-1,1.2){A}\rput(1,1.2){B}\rput(0,-2.1){C}
    \psline(0,1.3)(.4,2.3)  \uput[20](.3,2.4){$?$}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

creates a `<file>.pdf` and *no* `<file>-pics.pdf`!

Using `auto-pst-pdf` with for example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-venn}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \psframe(-2.8,-2.8)(2.8,2.8)
    \psVenn[bgcircle=false](-1,.5)(0,-1)(1,.5){1.5}{4}
    \rput(-1,1.2){A}\rput(1,1.2){B}\rput(0,-2.1){C}
    \psline(0,1.3)(.4,2.3)  \uput[20](.3,2.4){$?$}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

creates a helper file `<file>-pics.pdf` which collects *all* images as single pages which will be included automatically into the pdf.

Using documentclass `standalone` *and* package `auto-pst-pdf` id senseless, because
`standalone` itself creates the images!

Comment: When I compile the first code of you ( I use pdflatex.exe --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex also pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex ), compiler take error. why ?. P/s: The second code works smoothly with pdflatex.exe --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Comment: `standalone` _and_ PStricks can only be used with `xelatex` or `latex->dvips-ps2pdf` and _not_ with `pdflatex`. Only the second example can be run with `pdflatex --shell-escape ...`

Comment: Wow, I see. Thank you for your interpretation. :-)). I understood.